# Why don't Tick's powers hurt Billy in the 13th Reality series?

Tags: james-dashner, the-13th-reality

Tick has powers over Chikar'da revealed throughout the books. They are caused by:

> All of Tick's Alterants (doppel-gangers) being dead in other Realities, so their "soulkins" went to him.

If this is so, how was Billy able to bully him in the first book? His powers should have burst out of him and hurt if not killed Billy.

Answer (score 2):

At first, he didn't even know that he had power over Chikar'da. Also, he was not trained, and through his ignorance, his power of course did not show. He only started to realise his full potential after he was introduced to M.G.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't intentional. He didn't know that it was Chikar'da that was bursting out of him until Reginald Chu told him, so I find it hard to believe that just knowing about Chikar'da could cause accidental effects.

Comment: Chikar'da was bursting out of him thorough unknown methods that isn't described in the book. So, obviously he wasn't able to control the flow of Chikar'da in order to stop Billy from bullying him.